# In a chunked file transfer, is there a way for the server to provide the browser with an estimated file size?

Tags: express, http, browser, http-headers, file-transfer

I have a web page that allows users to download logs from the server. Due to the nature of the logging, these log downloads can be quite massive (billions of database records). The amount of data is too much for the server to process at once, so the server is streaming the data from the database, piping it through a CSV encoder, gzip encoder, then to the response object.

Everything works great except the file download shows "Unknown time left" in the browser.

Is there a way for a web server to send the browser an estimated total transfer size? Even better would be if there's a way for the server to continuously update the browser with this estimate. I can't determine an exact file size, but I can generate a pretty close estimate in advance, and improve that estimate as the download progresses.

To clarify, I know I can create my own progress bar on the web page itself, I'm wondering if there's an "official" way to do this so that the integrated file download dialog in the browser will display the estimated time to completion.